# C# Regex to find two commas separated by possible whitespace

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using C# to process some JavaScript code, and encounter a situation where an object inside another object is removed, so that I'm left with two consecutive commas, either with or without whitespace between them. I want to find them and replace with a single comma.

I tried this regex in [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to find the two consecutive commas:

```
,\s*,
```

But I'm not getting any matches. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Here's an example input:

```
window.Something = {
​    O1: {
​       F1: "A"
​    },
​    ,
​    O3: {
​        F2: "C"
​    },
​    O4: {
​        F3: "D"
​    }
​}
```

Comment: Another life-hack: paste your string into the [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sGF62a/1) text or regex field, you will see you do not have whitespace only.

Comment: Could there ever be two such commas inside a value, e.g. `F1: "A,,B"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content contains a `200B  ZERO WIDTH SPACE` between the commas separated by "whitespace". Since the char does not belong to whitespace, you need to add it to the pattern.

Use

```
,[\s\u200B]*,
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2C%5B%5Cs%5Cu200B%5D*%2C&i=window.Something%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20O1%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F1%3A%20%22A%22%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%2C%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20O3%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F2%3A%20%22C%22%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20O4%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F3%3A%20%22D%22%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%7D)

Alternatively, just add the whole [`\p{Cf}` "Other, format" Unicode category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cf/list.htm):

```
,[\s\p{Cf}]*,
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2C%5B%5Cs%5Cp%7BCf%7D%5D*%2C&i=window.Something%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20O1%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F1%3A%20%22A%22%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%2C%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20O3%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F2%3A%20%22C%22%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20O4%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F3%3A%20%22D%22%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%E2%80%8B%7D)

Whenever you have doubt what kind of input you are dealing with, use some hex tool. I prefer to quickly check the strings at [r12 Unicode code conveter](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) that, together with the [UniView tool](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/), is a great resource to check Unicode symbols in the string input (no affiliation, just a regular user for years).

Comment: `,\W*,` seems to work just as well for the OP's example.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Quite possible, the point is there is not only whitespace there. `,\W+,` also matches commas, so it will match `,,,,,,,`, too. There may be other solutions, sure.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is a char **·** in between whitespace and commas. So, you have to use this char in your regex. Below regex will work with the char and without the char. I've replace two commas in Regex101 example. Please check example Regex:

Regex:

**,(\s*\​·\s*|\s*),**

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/iZXCoQ/1).

Unicode Char of the symbol: `\u200b`
Html Char of the symbol: `&#8203;`

Comment: You could at least suggest an optional group based regex. It is bad practice to use alternations that match at the same location inside a string.